# Find element in first column of a list, but return the element in the second column

Tags: python

I'm really new to Python and I'm trying to perform the following

I have two lists, one of them is like

list 1:

```
['elem11','elem12','elem13'],

['elem21','elem22','elem23'],

['elem31','elem32','elem33']
```

And the other one

list2:

```
['elem11', value1],

['elem12', value2],

['elem13', value3],

['elem21', value4],
...
```

list2 contains all of the elements from list1 with its respective values.

I want to generate a third list like

list3:

```
['result line1 from list1', value1*value2*value3],

['result line2 from list1', value4*value5*value6],

['result line3 from list1', value7*value8*value9],
```

The elements in list1 and list2 are not at all in order, so I have to be able to match each element from list1 to its value from list2.

I tried using something like

```py
for i in range(3)
   if list1[i][0] in list2
      ...
   if list1[i][1] in list2
      ...
   if list1[i][2] in list2
      ...
```

But already I don't know how to get the values of the second column from list2

What functions should I use?

Comment: can you provide a more concrete example of input and output, what is the data type of `value`? is it supposed to be `'result line1 from list1'` in `list3` or is it a representation of something else

Comment: For your `list2` I think you should use a dictionary instead, like `d = {'elem11': value1, ...}`. Because then you can just do `[d[item] for l in list1 for item in l]` or similar.

Comment: Are `elemX` from `list1` all unique and only appears one time in `list2`?

Comment: 'elem' and 'result lineX from list 1' are both strings. 'value' is a float number.
Each element in list1 has only one correspondent in list2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Assuming all `elemX` from `list1` are unique and appears only one time in `list2`.

It would be easy to get the value if you change the `list2` to a dict.

```
list2_dict = {item[0]: item[1] for item in list2}
```

Then traverse over `list1` and get the values

```
list3 = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list3.append([f"result line{i+1} from list1", list2_dict[list1[i][0]] * list2_dict[list1[i][1]] * list2_dict[list1[i][2]])
```

Comment: I appreciate how concise this code is. It worked perfectly too.

Comment: For `key,val in list2` would be more pythonic, imo. Also, this assumes that list1 *always* consists of triplets, which is not specified. Further, I would even say that it definitely isn't always like that, otherwise he could have made them tuples.
Also, I heavily criticise `for i in range(len(list1))`. This alone should make this *not* the accepted answer. Best practice would be `for list1_elem in list1`, or, if you definitely *need* the `i`, `for i, list1_elem in enumerate(list1)`.

Comment: Also, don't append sub-lists to list3, use tuples. There just isn't any reason why you should use lists there.

Comment: @Finomnis is there any reason why I shouldn't use list? I know tuples work too.

Comment: Because that's not what lists are for, it is just the wrong tool for the wrong purpose. Not 'best practice'. The technical reason would be, it's slower. The style in which you are coding is strongly influenced by the C coding style, which is in most cases wrong for python. I don't really care how you code your own projects, but if you give advice on stackoverflow, you should really stick to best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong datastructure there. Instead of having a list, you want a dict.

Either create a dict directly:

```
list2_dict = {
   'elem11': value1,
   'elem12': value2,
   'elem13': value3,
   'elem21': value4
}
```

or create one from the list, if you can't change the fact that you start out with a list:

```
list2 = [
   ['elem11', value1],
   ['elem12', value2],
   ['elem13', value3],
   ['elem21', value4]
]
list2_dict = {key:val for key,val in list2}
```

You can then iterate over list1 and construct your list3:

```
list3 = []
for i, list1_row in enumerate(list1):
    row_sum = 0
    for list1_el in list1_row:
        row_sum += list2_dict[list1_el]
    list3.append(("result line" + str(i+1) + " from list1", row_sum))
```

```
# list3:
[
   ('result line1 from list1', <some number>),
   ('result line2 from list1', <some number>),
   ('result line3 from list1', <some number>)
]
```

Also, note that list3 doesn't contain sub-lists, but tuples. Don't use lists if you know the number of elements that will be in there. Use tuples instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked like a charm. Now I understand the interest of dictionaries